# Entering an ARRAY into a MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to enter data into a MySQL database using PHP from an array named $linkarray. I have been unable to do so at all..

```
//Sorry for this awful code ;/
$mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15, Col16, Col17, Col18, Col19, Col20, Col21, Col22, Col23, Col24, Col25, Col26, Col27, Col28, Col29, Col30, Col31, Col32, Col33, Col34,Col35, Col36,Col37, Col38, Col39, Col40, Col41, Col42, Col43, Col44, Col45, Col46, Col47, Col48, Col49, Col50, Col51, Col52, Col53, Col54, Col55, Col56, Col57, Col58) VALUES ('$linkarray[0]', '$linkarray[1]', '$linkarray[2]', '$linkarray[3]', '$linkarray[4]', '$linkarray[5]', '$linkarray[6]', '$linkarray[7]', '$linkarray[8]', '$linkarray[9]', '$linkarray[10]', '$linkarray[11]', '$linkarray[12]', '$linkarray[13]', '$linkarray[14]', '$linkarray[15]', '$linkarray[16]', '$linkarray[17]', '$linkarray[18]', '$linkarray[19]', '$linkarray[20]', '$linkarray[21]', '$linkarray[22]', '$linkarray[23]', '$linkarray[24]', '$linkarray[25]', '$linkarray[26]', '$linkarray[27]', '$linkarray[28]', '$linkarray[29]', '$linkarray[30]', '$linkarray[31]', '$linkarray[32]', '$linkarray[33]', '$linkarray[34]', '$linkarray[35]', '$linkarray[36]', '$linkarray[37]', '$linkarray[38]', '$linkarray[39]', '$linkarray[40]', '$linkarray[41]', '$linkarray[42]', '$linkarray[43]', '$linkarray[44]', '$linkarray[45]', '$linkarray[46]', '$linkarray[47]', '$linkarray[48]', '$linkarray[49]', '$linkarray[50]', '$linkarray[51]', '$linkarray[52]', '$linkarray[53]', '$linkarray[54]', '$linkarray[55]', '$linkarray[56]', '$linkarray[57]') ")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: any error while inserting data?

Comment: What was the error-message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
$mysql_query
```

to

```
mysql_query
```

remove `$` from `mysql_query`

Comment: Thanks guys. I got it finally!

Answer (score 0):

1. When you have to insert array elements you need to use {} around them
2. remove $ in font fo mysql_query

so try this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (Col1, Col2, Col3,....) VALUES ('{$linkarray[0]}', '{$linkarray[1]}', '{$linkarray[2]}', '{$linkarray[3]}' ......")
```

and you should be fine ..

Answer (score 0):

$db_column_array = array('col1','col2','col3',......);
// You can use schema table for get table column

$query = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME ( implode($db_column_array, ',') ) VALUES ( implode($db_column_data_array, ',') )";